# How convert JSON into an object pass to a function like options

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, application-settings

I need help to convert a JSON like this

{
"phrase": [{
"content_type": "text",
                    "title": "blablabla 1",
                    "payload": "blabla",
                    "text": ""
                }, {
                    "content_type": "text",
                    "title": "blablabla 2",
                    "payload": "blabla",
                    "text": ""
                }, {
                    "content_type": "text",
                    "title": "blablabla 3",
                    "payload": "blabla",
                    "text": ""
                }],
                "ogg": "true",
                "custom": "true"
         }

To an object used in a function as "options"(or "settings", you know) like this

```
function(){
  options = {
       phrase: [
                {
                    content_type: "text",
                    title: "blablabla 1",
                    payload: "blabla",
                    text: ""
                },
                {
                    content_type:"text",
                    title:"blablabla 2",
                    payload: "blabla"
                },
                {
                    content_type:"text",
                    title:"blablabla 3",
                    payload: "blabla"
                }
       ],
       ogg: true,
       custom: true
  }

  return options;
}
```

Is it possibile in anyway? Thank you!

Comment: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(options);
```

It will give you object and using the dot(.) operator you can access the data inside the object

Comment: Thank you so much. I used JSON.parse and correct a bug about double quotes around value true (value of 'ogg' and 'custom' keys)